# I need a trick to simulate a caret on a label

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, format

Actually, I'm using a custom numeric keyboard which is bound to a label (using AngularJS). With this keyboard, I can switch from a character to another thanks to arrow keys (to delete/modify/insert a character).

Now, I would need a 'trick' to show which character is focused (a kind of caret or something underline the focused character).

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the :focus pseudo state (I've just set the background-color, you can set the text-decoration but :before text, etc.)

```
[role="button"]:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

with HTML

```
<a href="#" role="button">
    A
</a>
<a href="#" role="button">
    B
</a>
```

```css
 [role="button"]:focus {
   background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
 <a href="#" role="button">
  A
 </a>
<a href="#" role="button">
  B
 </a>
```

Comment: What I need is to format the focused character in the label.

Comment: Could you post your code or a subset of it that shows this functionality?

Comment: HTML :

`<div class="amount ng-binding">54632</div>`

amount is bound to my custom keyboard, when I click on a key a new character is added in the div markup. I would like to set the background  color of a character of the string (using the character index)